# Jmeter time and date dynamic change

Tags: jmeter

I have created a Test plan in which there is date and time being passed in the parameters...I need to change the parameters dynamically so that when I run the test plan a new date and time is generated....the parameters look like this:

Name.                  Value

request       :    2018-04-08 22:13:51

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [__time](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function

> The time function returns the current time in various formats.

Enter your format as the first paramater `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`

Enter your variable name as second parameter:

```
 ${__time(yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss, Value)}
```

Comment: Can u please explain in steps how and where should I add it? Please? I don't know from where that function should be added from?

Comment: Just a question would the variable be passed anywhere else? like should I create a new one in the name part directly it would consider it right?

Comment: @Mehvish it will create a variable that will be available in your thread flow execution