# Unable to pass dynamic and unique date values in JMeter

Tags: date, groovy, jmeter, jmeter-5.0, parameterization

I have a request payload(JSON format) which has an array with 1000 objects and each object has 6 key value pairs out of which 5 I’m reading from the csv file using parameterization and the 6th key has to be a unique date value of a future date for each of the object in the array.

I tried this with time-shift function which works for 1 iteration but I want to execute it for n- number of iterations.

I checked for groovy code for this but I have no knowledge of groovy and have started learning it.

How can I achieve this in JMeter.

Also, on reading time-shift function from HTTP Request Defaults-Parameters or from the Test Plan-User Defined Variables it does not read different date for each object, it duplicates same date of the first variable in each object.

```
{
  “deviceNumber": “XX”,
  “array: [
    {
      “keyValue1: “${value1_ReadFromCSV}”,
      "keyValue2”: “${value2_ReadFromCSV}”,
      "keyValue3”: “${value3_ReadFromCSV}”,
      "keyValue4”: “${value4_ReadFromCSV}”,
      "keyValue5”: “${value5_ReadFromCSV}”,
      "keyValue6”: "2020-05-23” (Should be dynamically generated)
    },
    {
      “keyValue7: “value7_ReadFromCSV”,
      "keyValue8”: "value8_ReadFromCSV",
      "keyValue9”: "value9_ReadFromCSV",
      "keyValue10”: "value10_ReadFromCSV",
      "keyValue11”: "value11_ReadFromCSV",
      "keyValue12”: "2020-05-24” (Should be dynamically generated)
    },
    .
    .
    .
    .
    {
      “keyValue995: “value995_ReadFromCSV”,
      "keyValue996”: "value996_ReadFromCSV",
      "keyValue997”: "value997_ReadFromCSV",
      "keyValue998”: "value998_ReadFromCSV",
      "keyValue999”: "value999_ReadFromCSV",
      "keyValue1000”: "2025–12-31” (Should be dynamically generated)
    }
  ]
}
```

I have got the partial solution to this, by reading the csv file line by line and storing each line into a variable using groovy. However, I don't want to store directly the line into the variable but to create a JSON object like above from each line of csv file with a unique future date for each object which is in the array.

The csv file is : (Note: I have removed column for date column in csv as I no longer need it.)

```
deviceNumber,keyValue1,keyValue2,keyValue3,keyValue4,keyValue5,keyValue7,keyValue8,keyValue9,keyValue10,keyValue11,keyValue12,keyValue13,keyValue15,keyValue15,keyValue16
01,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring
02,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring
03,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring
.
.
.
1000,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring,somestring
```

Kindly suggest any reference/example to do this.

Comment: Can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49745549/jmeter-time-and-date-dynamic-change

Comment: Thanks @Rao I have gone though the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49745549/jmeter-time-and-date-dynamic-change earlier as well it doesn't fulfill the requirment I have for multiple iterations. Also, I did tried with timeshift function in: 1. User defined variables at test plan level  and 2. Parameters in HTTP Request Defaults.

Answer (score 0):

I provide only generic instructions:

1. You can dynamically construct request body using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor)
2. You can read CSV file into memory using [File.readLines()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#readLines()) function
3. You can build JSON out of the values from the CSV file using [JsonBuilder](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html) class

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)